# Phonegap camera API save picture taken to camera roll

Tags: camera, save, cordova

Is it possible using the Cordova camera API to take a picture and then store it locally in the camera roll on iOS and Android? I know its possible, but does it involve native code somehow or can it be done in pure HTML? The documentation doesn't say anything about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the device's gallery?

If so, just use FILE_URI for Camera.DestinationType option.

Reference: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#cameraOptions

Answer (score 15):

Simply add `saveToPhotoAlbum: true` in `cameraOptions` param.

For example

```js
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail,
{
  quality: 50,
  destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
  saveToPhotoAlbum: true
});
```

`saveToPhotoAlbum` is set to `false` by default.

[Reference](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#cameraOptions)